# Problems with RD-Navbar don't work on angular

Tags: angular

Mark the following error: "***Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'***"
And if I remove the brackets, it just doesn't do anything.

Any idea to solve it

```
<div class="rd-navbar-nav-wrap">
                        <ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
                            <li class="rd-nav-item"><a class="rd-nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="rd-nav-item"><a class="rd-nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</a></li>
                            <li class="rd-nav-item"><a class="rd-nav-link" routerLink="/services" routerLinkActive="active">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="rd-nav-item"><a class="rd-nav-link" routerLink="/contact" routerLinkActive="active">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Did you import [`RouterModule`](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial) in your application appropriately?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it's still the same